# Why is "Good Night!" dismissive

Tags: phrases, word-usage

To start off let us construct a situation were I am walking along and I pass another person. Depending on the time of day and to be polite I say one of the following:

1. "Good Morning!"
2. "Good Evening!"
3. "Good Night!"
4. "Good Day!"

Now 1 and 2 are common welcoming and polite gestures and I have no problem with their use. However the problem lies with 3: Why is it so dismissive compared with 1 and 2?

If I said "Good Night!" to somebody when walking at around 11 p.m why does it sound like I am putting them to bed?

Finally as a related matter, why is 4 not used too often? In other languages 4 seems to be more common then an equivalent "Hello!" and sometimes 4 and "Hello!" posses the same.meaning.

Comment: To be not dismissive, use *Good Evening* (even at midnight!?), instead, it's just the convention. Use *Good Night* to suggest an end to the conversation for the day.

Comment: As for why not *Good Day*, once again it is the convention, not language as such, just as you could ask why *Good Morning* and not *Fine Morning*? After all, we do say *Have a nice day*, don't we all?

Comment: That was my first thought too. "different meanings; that's just how it is". And phrases like "have a good time!" Does "goodbye" count? But I do wonder if there is a historical reason for the difference.

Comment: When you say “Good [time of day]”, you are essentially _wishing_ someone a pleasant [time of day]. One mostly wishes someone a pleasant night (in the older sense, which refers not to just late evening, but more or less to the time when most people normally sleep) when saying goodbye to them for the day, not expecting to see them until the next day. I find it more interesting that ‘good day’ (which means ‘hello’ in all other Germanic languages) has come to be unambiguously dismissive in English, i.e., “May you enjoy the rest of your day, for I shall have nothing more to do with you now!”.

Comment: Have you not read Tolkien's humorous exploitation of the different semantic and pragmatic senses of ['Good Morning!'](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/14559-good-morning-said-bilbo-and-he-meant-it-the-sun)?

Comment: @ Janus Bahs Jacquet: Not in Australia (though a more phonetic spelling is usual).

Comment: @Edwin, I'd say in Australia, _g’day_ is a greeting and _good day_ (pronounced very clearly as two words) is a dismissal. But surely the greeting preserves the original meaning of the phrase, and the dismissal is a later shift, for whatever reason it occurred.

Comment: @ Janus I confess that I'm unfamiliar with the popularity of the 'Good day' usage in Oz.

Comment: Question: _If I say "Good Night!" to somebody when walking at around 11pm, why does it sound like I am putting them to bed?_ Answer: Because that's what we say when we are putting children to bed.

Answer (score 3):

In American English, "good morning," "good afternoon," and "good evening" are all commonly used as greetings.

"Good day," by contrast, can actually be used fairly dismissively in its own right, especially if there is a name or title following it: "Good day, madame!" or, more famously, "Good day, sir!"

"Good night," on the other hand, tends to be used as a *farewell* rather than a greeting. To some extent, I suspect this is a psychological matter: even though we often use "night" as a substitute for "evening," I think in general we associate "night" with much later times than "evening," where we're not normally expecting to have company. Therefore, using "good night" in that manner seems unnatural.

It's the same principle in other languages, such as French and German. You'd use "Bonsoir" or "Guten Abend" as a greeting, but not "Bonne nuit" or "Gute Nacht."

Comment: The question asks *why* this should be so.

Comment: I've revised the answer a bit.

Answer (score 1):

All of those can be a greeting or a dismissal, depending on how you enunciate.

"Good xxxx!" is a perfectly acceptable way to hail an acquaintance, and can also be used to dismiss someone you don't wish to speak to any more.

"Good night!" is a less common greeting than the others, but still acceptable.

Comment: At least in modern US usage, I do not think you will find *Good night* as a greeting, but only as a departing statement (and often shortened to *Night*).

Comment: I've only ever noticed "Good night" used when someone is actually going to bed (and not just children), synonymous with "Sleep well", so using it as a more general salutation, related to time of day and not action, would certainly sound dismissive or downright inappropriate. Is this the norm elsewhere?