# Is "goodnight" the right wish to say in the evening, say 5 pm?

Tags: word-choice

In the evening, when we part after the day's work, my colleagues wish me "goodnight" and I don't feel it right. What is the right thing to say in the evening (5 pm) when we part with our colleagues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“Good night” or “good evening”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13142/good-night-or-good-evening)

Comment: This might have been a better question for [ell.se]. Don't worry about it now, but you might want to check that out for next time.

Comment: Check out this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144766/why-is-good-night-dismissive I said in a comment there that "good night" is usually used when people are actually going to bed, but seeing your question, I remember hearing it in this same context, at the end of work. It is maybe not so common, but I think it works, so long as it is at least evening. Here it seems to be short for "Have a good night", rather than synonymous with "Sleep well", in the sense that you aren't wishing someone a good evening but then no more good later on! So you could say "Have a good night".

Comment: Have a good night.

Answer (score 3):

"Good evening" is usually used as a greeting, not for departure. "Good night" can be used for a 5pm departure, but generally it is reserved for a time past 6pm or so. An intermediate could be "have a good evening."

Comment: I think this is the wrong way round. "Good evening" **can** be used on departure, but "Good night" is **never** used as a greeting.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Don't the Irish sometimes say 'good night' as a greeting? I feel sure I have heard it used in that way somewhere.

Comment: I agree that "Have a good night" is different than "Good night." Significantly different, even.

Answer (score 0):

"Good Night" can be used only when we are going to bed but we can use "Have a good night" while leaving an office or a meeting.

"Good Evening" can't be used at the time of departure as it sounds like a greeting.

Answer (score -1):

"Good evening" is most commonly used as a greeting, whereas "Good night" is a farewell.